# SQLalchemy brokenpipeline 2006 and then PendingRollbackError

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, discord.py

I've been making a discord bot which uses MySQL as a database but every so often (after approx. 24h) it gives the following errors:

> ```
> Command raised an exception: OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2006, "MySQL server has gone away
> ```
>
> (BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe'))") [SQL: SELECT warnings.uid AS
> warnings_uid, warnings.swarnings AS warnings_swarnings  FROM warnings
> WHERE warnings.uid = %(uid_1)s   LIMIT %(param_1)s] [parameters:
> {'uid_1': 405877911753588736, 'param_1': 1}] (Background on this error
> at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)

and ever since I've added session.rollback() it's started to give me:

PendingRollbackError: Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Have you read the docs on [Dealing with Disconnects](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/pooling.html?highlight=recycle#dealing-with-disconnects)?

Comment: Thank you so much! I seem to have read over that